# PHP xlsx header

Tags: php, header, xlsx

so this works:

myphpfile.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('myfile.pdf');
?>
```

that php file is called here and the PDF download works fine:

```
<a class = "oglasavanje" href = "../../cjenik/myphpfile.php">download</a><br/>
```

but this doesn't work:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
readfile('myfile.xlsx');
?>
```

both .pdf and .xlsx files are in the same folder. When I click on the 'download' link the download windows pops up, I save the file, but the file can't be opened. It gives me the following error:

> Excel cannot open the file 'myfile.xlsx' because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

The file opens fine when I open it manually (i.e. without downloading it via the link)

I'm using WAMP, if that's of importance.

Any help is appreciated.

--- EDIT ---

I've found this piece of code on php.net:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

so the final code looks like this and it works:

```
$file = "myfile.xlsx";
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
flush(); 
readfile($file);
```

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: Do you calculate and send the size of the file?

Comment: Also, its helpful to know which browsers this fails in. IE has been known to have some issues downloading files of some types in some conditions.

Comment: I didn't calculate and send the size of the file (and I don't know how to do that).
It's failing in Firefox.

Comment: you read the file and count the bytes. There's a guy below talking about some of the other headers that might help.

Comment: It would be great an exit; instruction just after readfile($file);

Answer (score 7):

Depends on your browsers  so many things can cause such behavior such as `Content-length` , `Cache-Control` etc

Also Change

`Content-type` to `Content-Type`

`Content-disposition` to `Content-Disposition`

Try

```
$file = "myfile.xlsx" ;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file );
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile('myfile.xlsx');
```

Comment: Explain .. what do you mean it did not work ? what exactly is the error you are getting .... just tested it it works here

Comment: The error is explained in the original post. In the meantime I've figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your web browser, the filename may not be saving fully with periods. If the filename is incomplete, you can try and replace this header:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx');
```

with

```
$filename = "myfile.xlsx";
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($filename);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
readfile($filename);
return;
```

This solution works for me, but when i'm trying to open downloaded file i'm getting an error. For .pdf file is just empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "abc.xls";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Can you explain why your solution is better than the accepted one, from six years ago? And could you ident the code?